# How to get only minute from material date time picker

Tags: android, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm using `com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.0.0` for **DateTime** chooser. But I want only minute to be highlighted. I don't want the hour.

Any idea how to achieve this?

```
public void timeSet() {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
            String time;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " date1 :"+ minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    },now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);

    try {
        final Activity activity = OrderDetailsActivity.this;
        tpd.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Any help would be appriciated. TIA**

Comment: I've added the code now. please check it. this is what i tried

Comment: We cann't restrict hours in that library. only timePickerDialog.enableMinutes(false) and timePickerDialog.enableSeconds(false) we can only restrict minutes and seconds

Comment: any other option to get only minute @MavyaSoni

Comment: Need to change library or use @akash93 answer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like the library has methods to be able to do this. But as a hack you could use `setMinTime` and `setMaxTime` methods to restrict the user to select time periods less than an hour.

Edit:
If you want the UI to be different I would suggest creating your own widget using the `RadialPickerLayout` provided by the same library and modifying it to suit your needs

Comment: actually after doing this, firstly hour will highlighted but I want firstly minute shd be highlited

Comment: Like I said this is just a hack since the library itself doesn't provide methods to do so explicitly. Btw there's also `setTimeInterval` which you can use to reduce the window.

Comment: yes looking for `RadialPickerLayout` if it works, definitely I'll accept the answer